# How to encode CommonsMultipartFile with base 64 in jsp page?

Tags: java, json, ajax, jsp

I want send **CommonsMultipartFile** from ajax call to server when user select the file. File can not be directly send through **JSON** as it gives the error mentioned here([JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of CommonsMultipartFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626067/jsonmappingexception-can-not-construct-instance-of-commonsmultipartfile)).

Is there any way to encode this (CommonsMultipartFile) in the client side (JSP page) to generate string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post gives the solution [Image convert to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710147/image-convert-to-base64).

**e.target.result;** gives 64 base encoded string.

And this post [Convert base64 string to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979842/convert-base64-string-to-image) explain how we can decode in the server side.